Monotonicity of the sequence$\left\{\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3n-1}\right\}$.
I'm studying the monotonicity of the sequence $\{x_n\}$ with
$$x_n=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3n-1},\quad n=1,2,\cdots.$$
As far as I get is the following:
$$x_1=\frac12<x_2=\frac8{15}<x_3=\frac{13}{24},$$
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_{n+2}-x_n &=& \frac{1}{3n+5}+\frac{1}{3n+3}+\frac{1}{3n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\\&>&\frac{3}{3n+3}-\frac{1}{n+1} = 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
i.e. both the sequences $\{x_{2n-1}\}$ and $\{x_{2n}\}$ are strictly increasing and
$$\frac12\leq x_n\leq\frac{n}{n+1}<1.$$
Actually, we can also get the limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{n+2k-1}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{1+2\cdot\frac{k-\frac12}{n}}
=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{{\rm{d}}x}{1+2x}=\frac{\log3}{2}.$$


What I want to konw is the monotonicity of the sequence $\{x_n\}$,
I guess that
$$x_n<x_{n+1},\quad n=1,2\cdots.$$
But I'm stuck by dealing with the difference
$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac1{n+2k}-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{n+2k-1}.$$


Any conments and hints will welcome.

Related. More similar questions via Approach0.

@Jyrki Lahtonen
There is no proof for the monotonicity of the sequence {} and only the lower bound and monotonicity of ${x{2n-1}}$ and ${x_{2n}}$. Thank you !

Are you familiar with generalized harmonic numbers (or the polygamma function) ?

@ Claude Leibovici I'm sorry , I am not familiar with what you said.

Thanks the idea of @Wlod AA in the post Idea.
Use the identity (telescping sum):
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(n+2k-\frac32)(n+2k+\frac12)}
    =\frac1{2n+1}-\frac 1{6n+1}.$$
So the difference is
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}-x_n
=&\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{n+2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+2k-1}\\
=&\frac1{3n+2}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{(n+2k-1)(n+2k)}\\
=&\frac1{3n+2}-\left(\frac1{2n+1}-\frac 1{6n+1}\right)\\
&+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[\frac1{(n+2k-\frac32)(n+2k+\frac12)}-\frac1{(n+2k-1)(n+2k)}\right]\\
=&\frac1{3n+2}-\left(\frac1{2n+1}-\frac 1{6n+1}\right)\\
&+\frac34\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+2k-\frac32)(n+2k+\frac12)(n+2k-1)(n+2k)}\\
>&\frac1{3n+2}-\left(\frac1{2n+1}-\frac 1{6n+1}\right)\\
=&\frac{1}{(3n+2)(2n+1)(6n+1)}\\
>&0.
\end{align}
This implies that the sequences $\{x_n\}$ is strictly increasing.
